# How to set minimum width in resizable table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resizable

I made a resizing table using Jquery resizable. Now, i am facing a problem in it. The goal is:

1. I want to set a minimum width (ie.,) it will not resize beyond that width
2. When i resize one column, the width of another column should not change

I used minimum width for the first one, but it didnt work and i dont know what to do with the second one.

Please help me guys

Here is the link

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZkY4PB8XaHfAj7DPJuZN?p=preview)

```
<table id="table-css-border-1" class="ui-widget-content">
    <tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: _When i resize one column, the width of another column should not change_ Then what are you going to do with the increased or reduced width? how you want to manage?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#max-min

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Actually, my requirement is when one column width is reduced or increased, it should not affect the another column and yes we can use colResizable, but i want to use resizable

Comment: Then how want to manage increased/reduced space?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao ok..here is the scenario. If the table width is 400px, and if i increase the column width to 450px by dragging, then there should be a horizontal scrollbar. Can we do that?

Comment: So you want to increase or decrease table size itself..??

Comment: yes. and if one column width is increased or reduced, then the other column width should not change. Eg. If table width is 200px and there are 4 column each with 50px, if i increase the first column width to 100px, then other column should not get affected ie., their width should be 50px. And by increasing the column width by 100px, table width should be 250px. can we do like this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but later i made of use `colResizable`

colResizable is a free jQuery plugin to resize table columns dragging them manually. It is compatible with both mouse and touch devices and has some nice features such as layout persistence after page refresh or postback. It works with both percentage and pixel-based table layouts

```
$("#sample").colResizable({
liveDrag:true
});
```

I am sure your issue will be resolved using this.

Have a look at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euka4rm3/)

for Docs about colResizable http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/#usage

Answer (score 0):

try adding minWidth in your function

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $("#table-css-border-1 tr th").resizable({
        handles: 'e',
        minWidth:100
      });
    });
</script>
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-minWidth